# Conversão de resposta em listas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pessoal estou com um pequeno problema em meu algorítimo tenho que receber um "nome de uma instituição" qualquer digitado pelo usuário e converte-lo em lista para usa-lo futuramente em outras condições porem esta convertendo pra string todas as letras do nome e colocando em uma lista ficando assim impossibilitado de usa-lo como uma nova lista declarada pelo "usuário" para usa em outras condições.

```
instituicão = []

    print("Digite o nome da instituição que deseja adicionar.\n 0 - Para 
    parar de adicionar\n")
    while True:
        instituicão_add = input("digite alguma instituicao")
        #Supor que o usuário botou "ADD"
        conversão_lista = list(instituicão_add)

        #funcionaria se tivesse em str mas o print vai sair como dito
        #ja  para o input direto nao sei qual condição bota para parar
        if instituicão_add == "0": #<<< ???  
            break
        else:
           instut.append(conv_list)
           print(instituicão)           
           #Ai no caso meu print sai se tiver str(input("")) assim [['a', 'd', 'd']]
           #O certo para min seria sair assim [["alguma coisa"]] 

for indice,na_lista in enumerate(instituicão):
    print(indice, "-", na_lista)

inst = int(input("\nQual instituição deseja escolher?"))

x = inst #recebendo o indice que seria pra entra na lista que desejasse

if inst == x:
         dinheiro = int(input("\nQuanto deseja doar?\n")
         instituicão[x].append(dinheiro)
         print("Obrigado por ajudar esta instituição")
         print(instituicão[x])
```

Aqui nesse ultimo "print" desejava que saia [["valor de dinheiro doado"]], pelo usuario dentro da instituicao adicionada por ele e transformada em lista que deveria retorna [["xxxxx"]], porem não estou conseguindo fazer este algorítimo funcionar assim se poderem me ajudar.

Comment: Python3 deixa você acentuar variáveis - mas não quer dizer que você deva faze-lo!  :-)   Mas se for fazer, é importante manter a consistência: A variável deveria ser `instituição`  (ou `instituicao`) - nunca `instituicão` - como você vai conseguir se lembrar de onde usou noms especiais ou não quando o programa for maior?

Comment: Alias-  tente usas os mesmos nomes para a mesma variável - ter uma "conversão_lista" que você tenta usar algumas linhas abaixo com o nome de "conv_list"  não vai ajudar seu programa a funcionar.

Comment: ei como guardo o valor recebido sem sobrescrever o anterior porque como e dicionario não estou conseguindo salva como faço em listas normais, tipo se na doação digito 1000 e quero doar novamente e digito 20 deveria fica guardado 1020 e não sobrescrever pra 20 e não tenho noção de como fazer isso em dicionario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, acho que entendi. Você quer guardar todas as instituicões digitadas pelo utilizador numa lista:

Porque não fazer uma lista de dicionários onde cada um armazena nome da institução e respetiva doação? Se percebi bem o problema, neste contexto penso que seria o melhor:

Python 3.x:

```
instituicoes = []
while True:
    instituicao_add = input("digite alguma instituicao") #ex: 'stack overflow pt'
    if(instituicao_add == 'exit'):
        break
    instituicoes.append({'nome': instituicao_add})

x = int(input("\nQual instituição deseja escolher?")) # ex: 0

while x >= len(instituicoes) or x < 0: # Verificar se index existe na nossa lista de instituicoes
    x = int(input("\nQual instituição deseja escolher?")) # ex: 0

dinheiro = int(input("\nQuanto deseja doar?\n"))

instituicoes[x]['doação'] = dinheiro # ex: 1000
print("Obrigado por ajudar esta instituição")
print(instituicoes[x]) # output: {'nome':'stack overflow pt', 'doação': 1000}

#para imprimir só o valor doado
print(instituicoes[x]['doação'])
```

Comment: Mas nesse caso não tenho como usa a "instituição" como lista dentro de lista pra depois "doar", pra alguma dessas instituição só percorrendo a lista pelo indice pra escolher alguma que esteja guardada, já tentei antes isso e tals, mas vlw ainda não da certo por esse fato porque depois não tenho como usala como uma lista informada pelo usuário guardada dentro de outra lista. E já o exit vai finalizar toda a execução eu só preciso da condição em modo de lista que faça entra no break.

Comment: Mas diga-me uma coisa... instituição é uma lista de strings ou uma lista de listas? Sendo assim não percebi bem o que quer armazenar dentro dessa var.

Um à parte: Podem surgir problemas por o noma da variável ter acentos

Comment: Instituição e a lista que recebe as listas com os nomes que o usuário informa o problema e que esta ficando em string e não lista dentro de lista tipo instituição =[ ] ai quando o usuario informace o nome da instituição a ser guardada na lista instituição = [[informada_pelo_usuário]] que tipo ele informaria em nome e o programa fizesse esse nome informado vira uma lista definida pelo usuario sem ter que adicionar manualmente cada instituição no código.Acento e tals botei aqui por costume de escrita  correta, mas no python mesmo não uso.

Comment: Se percebi bem então quer adicionar listas (de instituições). Vou editar em cima de acordo com a solução que possa resolver esse problema.

Comment: Exatamente com o que já aprendi e tentei algumas coisas mas avanças e não conseguir fazer isso de quando o "nome" digitado pelo usuário virase uma lista pra ser guardada dentro de outra lista

Comment: Pode testar esse código extamente como está, se percebi bem isso resolve o seu problema

Comment: Muito obrigado é pelo fato que não tive aulas de dicionario ainda mas compreendi perfeitamente muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: ei como guardo o valor recebido sem sobrescrever o anterior porque como e dicionario não estou conseguindo salva como faço em listas normais, tipo se na doação digito 1000 e quero doar novamente e digito 20 deveria fica guardado 1020 e não sobrescrever pra 20 e não tenho noção de como fazer isso em dicionario.